# How to find number of closed issues for a repository?

Tags: github-api

You can find the number of open issues for a project via the [Repositories > Get](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) method in GitHub's API.

But is there any way to find the number of closed issues or the total number of issues, without iterating over all issues? Such information is available on the issues page of each project, but it doesn't seem to be present in the API.

For example, on https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues:

[image: Issue count for Node repository]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Per [this issue comment](https://github.com/Digipalvelutehdas/github-viewer/issues/7#issuecomment-202837902), you can use the search API, rather than the issues API, to get an issue count. The [relevant API docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues) cover the use of a state filter in the search term.

> GET https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:nodejs/node+type:issue+state:closed

```
{
    "total_count": 6595,
    "incomplete_results": false,
    "items": [...]
}
```

As noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207654/how-to-find-number-of-closed-issues-for-a-repository/49209364?noredirect=1#comment122854277_49209364), as you only care about the *count* of the issues you can add `per_page=1` to the query parameters to minimise the data fetched, which might speed things up a bit.

Comment: if you are only interested in the total count, you can append `&page=0&per_page=1` to avoid loading too many issues

Answer (score 0):

Append `issues` to your URL and it should return all the issues, you can then calculate the number of objects and deduce which are open and which aren't.

An example call:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/anandkgpt03/test/issues
```

Comment: Not a deal : if You have repository with thousands of total issues, it will charge too much Github's API and You could be blocked.

Comment: You're right. Well, here's the next best thing I could find - https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/536#issuecomment-335001753

Comment: Also, there's open_issues and open_issues_count, so if we could find the total count, we can then subtract the open ones and get the number of closed ones.

Comment: open_issues and open_issues_count contains same number. It's duplicated data. It does not show total count of issues.

Comment: I understand, I'm just saying if we could somehow find the total number of issues we can then subtract open ones using open_issues.

Comment: Yep, and this Stackoverflow question is about it, how to find number of closed issues or total number of issues of a project :)