# Get the number of closed issues belong to a reposiroty using GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I have a list containing a couple of thousands of GitHub repositories' names.
I want to iterate this list and print for each repository the number of its closed issues.

Following this link [How to find a number of closed issues for a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207654/how-to-find-number-of-closed-issues-for-a-repository), two methods were suggested:

The first method was about using a **search** query:

```
state="closed"
params = {'per_page': 1, 'anon': 1}
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token ******'
}
url = "https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:{}+type:issue+state:{}".format(repo_name, state)
r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(r.json()['total_count'])
```

Although this method is working fine, I'm limited to sending up to 30 **search** quarries each minute, resulting in a significantly long time to complete.

The second method was about using a **core** query:

```
state="closed"
params = {'per_page': 1, 'anon': 1}
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token ******'
}
url = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/issues?state={}".format(repo_name, state)
r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(r.links)
# Filtering the number of pages from the last link ...
```

This solves the issue of limited queries as I'm limited to sending up to 5000 **core** quarries each hour.

The problem is that this query counts other objects than 'issue'.

For example, one repository I tested contained 3 closed issues.
The first method yield the number 3 (as expected), but the second method yield the number 4, as it included an additional **closed merge request**.

Any suggestion on how to solve one of those problems?

1. Increase the limit rate for **search** queries.
2. Use **core** query to filter only 'issue' objects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if [`gh issue list --state closed`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_list) would help in your case. It should take care of the pagination for you.

[Install the GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) first, and use [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) to authentication yourself.

Then:

```
gh issue list -R OWNER/REPO --state clone | wc -l
```